Neumann function for the heat operator
Consider the heat operator
$$ \mathcal{L}u := \epsilon (x,t) u_{xx} - u_t$$
where $x\in  [0,L]$, $t\in [0,+\infty)$, and $\epsilon : [0,L]\times [0,+\infty) \to (0,+\infty)$ is the diffusion coefficient. Furthermore, we let $\mathcal{N}(x,t;\xi,\tau)$ be the associated Neumann function, with $(x,t)\in [0,L]\times [0,+\infty)$, $(\xi,\tau)\in [0,L]\times [0,+\infty)$ and $t>\tau$.
I know that if $\epsilon$ is constant, then we have some upper-bounds on $|\mathcal{N}|$ and $|\mathcal{N}_\xi|$ that allow us to conclude that $\int_{0}^{t}\int_{0}^{1}|\mathcal{N}_\xi(x,t;\xi,\tau)|d\xi d\tau$, $\int_{0}^{t}|\mathcal{N}(x,t;1,\tau)|d\tau$ and $\int_{0}^{t}|\mathcal{N}(x,t;0,\tau)|d\tau$ can be made arbitrarily small by letting $t$ be sufficiently small.
I didn't find a similar result for a general varying $\epsilon$ (say, $\epsilon$ Hölder continuous). I tried to consult the book "Partial Differential Equations of Parabolic Type" by Avner Friedmann, and I found some inequalities on page 134 about a function $|\Gamma(x,t;\xi,\tau)|$ called the fundamental solution of the heat operator. These inequalities allow me to show that $\int_{0}^{t}\int_{0}^{1}|\Gamma_\xi(x,t;\xi,\tau)|d\xi d\tau$, $\int_{0}^{t}|\Gamma(x,t;1,\tau)|d\tau$ and $\int_{0}^{t}|\Gamma(x,t;0,\tau)|d\tau$ can be made arbitrarily small by letting $t$ be sufficiently small.
My main question is: Is $\Gamma(x,t;\xi,\tau)$ the same as the Neumann function that I am interested in? I suspect it might be, since it is used later in the book to derive the integral representation of parabolic PDEs, but I am not entirely sure. Could someone clarify this or point me to a reference that explicitly discusses upper-bounds on $\mathcal{N}$ and $\mathcal{N}_\xi$?
These things seem extremely classical for PDE specialists, but as a student in this field, I find it very difficult to find a reference explicitly stating such results ...

What is a Neumann function?

The Neumann function (I found this terminology in Friedmann's book and in some research articles) is called, by other authors, the Green function for the heat operator subject to Neumann boundary conditions. It verifies, as a function of $(x,t)$, the heat equation subject to Neumann boundary conditions, and with a dirac initial condition.
